# Pandas 2.0 dtype promotion seeming to produce arbitrary precision float

Tags: pandas, decimal, precision

Work is concerning financial reporting. In testing dtype promotion, I have written the following script (aware explicit dtype casting should be used in production code), and am noticing that above UInt64 values, pandas can convert to the `object` column dtype, storing python `int` objects.  When this column undergoes division, the output column is no longer of the python int type.  I would expect something like `np.float64` or `float` (with double-precision).  Checking the output returns `float`, though the representation is octuple-precision with non-float formatting.  Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def main():
    df = setup()
    print_full(df.dtypes)
    print('###########################')
    print_full(df['UInt256'].head())
    print(type(df.loc[0, 'UInt256']))
    print('###########################')
    df['A'] = df['UInt256'].div(2)
    print_full(df['A'].head())
    print(type(df.loc[0, 'A']))
    return


def setup():
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        pd.Series(np.arange(0, 2 ** 8), dtype=pd.UInt8Dtype()),
        columns=['UInt8'])
    df['UInt16'] = df['UInt8'] * 2 ** (2**3)
    df['UInt32'] = df['UInt16'] * 2 ** (2**4)
    df['UInt64'] = df['UInt32'] * 2 ** (2**5)
    df['UInt128'] = df['UInt64'] * 2 ** (2**6)
    df['UInt256'] = df['UInt128'] * 2 ** (2**7)
    return df


def print_full(x):
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
    pd.set_option('display.width', 2000)
    pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:20,.2f}'.format)
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
    print(x)
    if 'dtypes' in dir(x):
        print(x.dtypes)
    pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')
    pd.reset_option('display.max_columns')
    pd.reset_option('display.width')
    pd.reset_option('display.float_format')
    pd.reset_option('display.max_colwidth')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running this yields:

```
UInt8       UInt8
UInt16     UInt16
UInt32     UInt32
UInt64     UInt64
UInt128    object
UInt256    object
dtype: object
object
###########################
0                                                                               0
1     452312848583266388373324160190187140051835877600158453279131187530910662656
2     904625697166532776746648320380374280103671755200316906558262375061821325312
3    1356938545749799165119972480570561420155507632800475359837393562592731987968
4    1809251394333065553493296640760748560207343510400633813116524750123642650624
Name: UInt256, dtype: object
object
<class 'int'>
###########################
0                                                                                                     0.00
1   226,156,424,291,633,194,186,662,080,095,093,570,025,917,938,800,079,226,639,565,593,765,455,331,328.00
2   452,312,848,583,266,388,373,324,160,190,187,140,051,835,877,600,158,453,279,131,187,530,910,662,656.00
3   678,469,272,874,899,582,559,986,240,285,280,710,077,753,816,400,237,679,918,696,781,296,365,993,984.00
4   904,625,697,166,532,776,746,648,320,380,374,280,103,671,755,200,316,906,558,262,375,061,821,325,312.00
Name: A, dtype: object
object
<class 'float'>
```

Trying pandas column division on an object dtype column of int objects, expecting output of double-precision python float.  Result type checks as float but has comma separated formatting and 77 significant digits.  Using python 3.11.2, pandas 2.0.0rc, on a 2015 macbook...